# Complex limit proving

Tags: complex-analysis

For complex number $z$, how to prove the limit exits by definition

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} =1$$

By def I've tried, but I got a difference always greater than 1..

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: None of these related questions address the case where $z$ is taken to be a complex number.

Comment: @J.J. OK, sorry. I thought the arguments would also work for complex numbers, and that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital's rule is a local statement; it concerns the behavior of functions near a particular point. The global issues (multivaluedness, branch cuts) are irrelevant.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \stackrel{\text{de l'hopital}}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{cos(x)}{1}=1$$

Comment: I just worry about, if the limit not exits, the L'hospital rule would not hold, thus, can we use it to prove the limit exist..?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm inclined to No though. Sounds like circular logic to me.

Comment: ye... the derivative of $\sin x$ at $x=0$ require this limit exist, so, here we cannot use it to prove itself...